# How to show a login screen only once in android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this app that prompts the user to input their password when it starts. After successful login the next activity is menu. While in menu if i press the back button i go back to the login activity. Is it possible to show the login activity once and not have it show up when the user presses the back button?

Flow is like this:

```
             ______
            |      |
AppStart -> |Login | -> (successful) -> Menu
            |______| > (unsuccessful)    |
                ^_________|<_____________| (Back button)
```

Comment: Remember you have to check your logged-in state in every Activity's onStart or onResume() since you can re-enter the application from any of them, not just from launcher activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest, add the following attribute:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

This will prevent it from being added to the activity stack.

Answer (score 6):

**1) First Approach:**

Call `finish()` in your Login activity right after starting the next activity with `startActivity()`.

**2) Second Approach:**

Another approach is to add this attribute to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml: `android:noHistory="true"`

Example,

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:noHistory="true"/>
```

This attribute instructs Android to remove LoginActivity from the history stack once its navigated away from.

Comment: I downvoted at first because I have always been skeptical about calling `finish()` immediately after `startActivity()`... it never made sense to me and seemed unclear whether `finish()` would *always* be called after launching the new `Activity`. However, after sifting through the Google I/O 2012 source code it seems like this is actually perfectly acceptable... I trust Roman Nurik w/ my life :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood same as you I was confused at the begenning if code after startActivity() will get executed!! But once fetching the web I get a response that " In main thread code after startactivity() is always called before onPause() but this can affect the responsiveness of the app when transitioning to the next activity if    instructions take more then a few milleseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:excludeFromRecent = "true"` tag in Login Activity's manifest declaration.

like below

```
 <activity
       android:name=".loginScreen"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"

    </activity>
```

Comment: "recents" is different from the activity stack.

Comment: Yes, If he set this tag as true, And  called finish after Starting another activity. it will work

Comment: This is "recents": http://developer.android.com/design/media/ui_overview_recents.png